# Sorting based on date in Angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid

```
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Date": "8-27-2020 3:11:43 AM"
  },
   {
    "Id": 2,
    "Date": "10-27-2020 3:11:43 AM"
  },
   {
    "Id": 3,
    "Date": "9-27-2020 3:11:43 PM"
  },
   {
    "Id": 4,
    "Date": "7-27-2020 3:11:43 AM"
  }
]

sort() {
      a.sort(function (date1, date2) {
        return (new Date(date1.Date) < new Date(date2.Date))
          ? -1 : (new Date(date1.Date) > new Date(date2.Date)) ? 0 : 1;
      });
      }
```

i want to sort this array as per the date and it should work on IE browser.
the sorting output as per date should be

{
"10-27-2020 3:11:43 AM",
"9-27-2020 2:09:43 AM",
"8-27-2020 3:11:43 AM",
"7-27-2020 3:04:43 AM"
}

Answer (score 1):

Just  `array.sort( (a, b) =>new Date(b.Date) - new Date(a.Date));` is enough

Solution for you

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ugulxb

Comment: Thanks but it giving output in ascending order

Comment: It returns "10-27-2020 3:11:43 AM", "9-27-2020 3:11:43 PM", "8-27-2020 3:11:43 AM", "7-27-2020 3:11:43 AM"]
If you want to reverse order use `array.sort( (a, b) =>new Date(a.Date) - new Date(b.Date));`